# Printf prints more character than those contained in my string

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I have to write a program that acts like a shell. I wrote the function that gets the input from the user. I also wrote the function that splits it into arguments. **The first time I type something, it works well, but the second time, it prints different characters after the ones that I gave it.** I don't have to print it in the program. I was just doing it to see if it works correctly. I read a bunch of stuff online, but I can't figure out my error. I suppose it is in makeArgs(), but I can't pinpoint it.

Also, when I give it an input, the readline function adds a \n at the end of the string. I suppose it is from the fact that I press the enter key. I managed to solve the issue, by manually replacing it, but I would like to know if it is normal.

Any help really be appreciated.
Thank You

[Screenshot of Xterm after 2 inputs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7lb2.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int getText();
int makeArgs();

char *textEntre;
size_t nbCharacters;
char **arguments;

int main (void)
{

    while (1){
        getText();
        int nbArguments = makeArgs();
        for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
            printf("%s \n",arguments[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<nbArguments; i++){//free the char ptrs at the end
            free(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
    free(textEntre);
    free(arguments);
    return 0;
}

int getText(){
    size_t buffersize = 0;
    nbCharacters = getline(&textEntre, &buffersize, stdin);
    textEntre[nbCharacters-1] =' '; // when I press enter it regiter the enter as \n so I replace it with a space
    return 0;
}

int makeArgs(){
    arguments = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*20);
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int nbElem = 20; //the number of ptrs that can be in arguments
    for(i = 0; i<nbCharacters; i++){
       if(i == 20){ //increases the memory allocated if there are more than 20 arguments
            nbElem = nbElem *2;
            arguments = (char **)realloc(arguments, sizeof(char*)*nbElem);
       }
       if(textEntre[i] == '"'){ //checks for ""
            i++;
            while(textEntre[i] != '"'){
                i++;
            }
       }
       if(textEntre[i] == ' ' && textEntre[i-1] == ' '){ // eliminates useless spaces
            j++;
       }
       else if(textEntre[i] == ' '){ //save a single argument
           char * chptr;
           chptr = (char *)malloc(i-j+1); //giving +1 for the \0 at the end
           strncpy(chptr, &textEntre[j], i-j);
           arguments[k] = chptr;
           k++;
           j = i +1;
       }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chptr = (char *)malloc(i-j+1); //giving +1 for the \0 at the end
```

You properly allocated memory for that terminating `\0`, but where do you actually add that "\0 at the end"?

```
strncpy(chptr, &textEntre[j], i-j);
```

`strncpy` does not necessarily zero-terminate the destination buffer. You have to do it yourself.

In fact, in this specific application `strncpy` is a rather inappropriate function: it does not give you anything over ordinary `memcpy` and might be less efficient. You could just do

```
memcpy(chptr, &textEntre[j], i - j);
```

with potentially better efficiency. And, again, don't forget to zero-terminate the destination buffer.

Or you can use `sprintf` for the same purpose as follows

```
sprintf(chptr, "%.*s", i - j, &textEntre[j]);
```

which will produce a properly zero-terminated string in the destination. (Albeit you won't see `sprintf` used that way very often.)

Comment: That fixed it!! Thank you so much!! I changed it to memcpy and added the \0 manually.

Comment: @ryyker: That's what I meant by "generally". `strncpy`'s original purpose is not directly related to zero-terminated strings at all.